# Laravel define relationship with 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have below models in my application.

1. Model - Dealer
2. Model - Vehicle Type
3. Model - Part Category
4. Model - Part

We have a master data of VehicleTypes, PartCategories and Parts defined using below tables.

1. Table - Vehicle_Types_Master
2. Table - Part_Category_Master
3. Table - Parts_Master

We will also have to map Models in the below relationship.

1. Dealer can select multiple Vehicle types from the Vehicle Type master.
2. Dealer can select Part Categories for each Vehicle Type
3. Dealer can select Parts for each Part Category.

For the first mapping, I have ManyToMany relation ship between *Dealer* and *Vehicle Type* with mapping table *dealer_vehicle_type_config*

Model Dealer

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function vehicleTypes()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(VehicleType::class, 'dealer_vehicle_type_config', 'dealer_id', 'vehicle_type_id');
 }
```

Model VehicleType

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function dealers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Dealer::class, 'dealer_vehicle_type_config', 'vehicle_type_id', 'dealer_id');
}
```

To store the dealer selection of part category with vehicle type, and dealer's selection of part category with parts, I can define below mapping table with many to many relationship.

| dealer_vehicle_type_parts_config |
| --- |
| id |
| dealer_id |
| vehicle_type_id |
| part_category_id |

| dealer_part_category_parts_config |
| --- |
| id |
| dealer_id |
| part_category_id |
| parts_id |

But how can I define this relationship in Model based approach?

I can access vehicle types using below

```
$dealer = auth()->user()->dealer;
$vehicleTypes = $dealer->vehicleTypes();
```

Is it possible to define relationships dealer -> part-category -> part?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in Dealer model with a different approach

```
public function partsByCategory($catogory_id)
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Part::class, 'dealer_vehicle_type_parts_config', 'dealer_id', 'dealer_id')::where('part_category_id', $category_id);
}
```